# How can I subclass the Selection object in JavaScript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I would like to do the following:

```javascript
class MySelection extends Selection {
   constructor() {
       super()
   }
   someNewMethod1() {

   }
   someNewMethod2() {

   }
}
```

However, I am currently limited to doing `const instance = document.getSelection()`, and then adding static methods manually. There's no problem doing it this way, but I'm just curious whether there's a way to use class syntax for the Selection object -- after all, it is capitalized, so you'd expect to be able to instantiate it using `new Selection()` or subclassing it.

Comment: You don't create a Selection object with a constructor and thus you can't easily subclass it this way.  Instead, the browser provides a factory function `window.getSelection()` that makes an object for you.  So, you have no way of really making it create the subclass object you want.

Comment: What about prototypes? Selection.prototype.someNewMethod1 = function() {} does exactly what you want..

Comment: That adds a function to the prototype of the Selection object, but the function is unavailable when invoking `window.getSelection()`. I ended up just doing something like: `const mySel = window.getSelection()` and then tacking on methods: `mySel.someNewMethod1 = function() {}`. Since `window.getSelection()` retrieves the same instance each time, the method persists in the same manner as your example would have done if `Selection` were a normal constructor.

Comment: Why use a subclass at all? It'd be best to just make functions that accept the selection as an arg.

Answer (score 0):

I actually achieved this and it worked fine for me here is my code example

import moment from 'moment'
import _ from 'lodash'

```
class Model {
  constructor(props) {
    this.initialize(props)
  }

  initialize(props) {
    this.id = props.id && Number(props.id) || null
    this.createdAt = props.createdAt && moment(props.createdAt) || null
    this.updatedAt = props.updatedAt && moment(props.updatedAt) || null
    this.deletedAt = props.deletedAt && moment(props.deletedAt) || null
  }

  toJson() {
    const props = Object.assign({}, this)

    _.forOwn(props, (value, key) => {
      if (value instanceof moment) {
        props[key] = value.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
      }
    })
    return props
  }
}

import moment from 'moment'
import Model from './Model'
import User from './User'

class Article extends Model {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.initialize(props)
  }

  initialize(props) {
    super.initialize(props)

    this.slug = props.slug | ''
    this.title = props.title || ''
    this.description = props.description || ''
    this.content = props.content || ''
    this.published = props.published || false
    this.publishedAt = props.publishedAt ? moment(props.publishedAt) : null

    // relate user model
    this.user = props.user ? new User(props.user) : null
  }
}

export default Article
```

I can easily initiate the Article or Model class and use the instance or static functions like

```
const Article = new Article({ // });

Article.toJson();
```